# Looping through array response for get request

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework

I want to store the information that I get from `getLocation` in the location array and convert the value to float. But I don't know how to loop through to store the value

```
this.peopleservice.getLocation(ID)
   .subscribe(data =>{this.latcoor = data[x].lat,
    this.lngcoor=data[x].lng

   this.lat= parseFloat(this.latcoor);
   this.lng= parseFloat(this.lngcoor);

  this.location= [
            {latitude:this.lat, longitude:this.lng},
        ];
  });}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `for` loop like below:

```
this.peopleservice.getLocation(ID)
   .subscribe(data => {
    this.location = [];
    for (let item of data) {
      this.location.push({latitude: parseFloat(item.lat), longitude: parseFloat(item.lng)});
    }
  });
```